# In android viewpager 2 , dot indicator, want to disable click event form dot indicator, not working

Tags: android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator

I am using https://github.com/tommybuonomo/dotsindicator dot indicator when I click in any dot, it leads me to that particular page. I want to disable that click event. I have used `dots_indicator.isClickable = false` but it is not working. any suggestions would be very appreciable. Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After investing some time I found a workaround, which is working. I have created a View and cover the dot_indicatoer with that view and applied an empty setOnClickListener on that view. It is disabling the click event in the dot indicator

```
empty_view.setOnClickListener{ /*do nothing */}
```

and this is working like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

dotsIndicator.dotsClickable = false

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).